# Get values from HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get the values from a form I've created in HTML:
I'm using Javascript to try and get the values from the form, I've tried multiple ways of getting the values, at the moment it's this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("input");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      console.log(x.elements[i].value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="input">
  First Name: <br/>
  <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>

  Last Name: <br/>
  <select id="lastName" style="text-align: center;">
  </select><br/>

  <p>Date of Birth:</p><br />

  Day: <br/>
  <select id="dayDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
  </select><br/>
  Month: <br/>
  <select id="monthDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
  </select><br/>
  Year: <br/>
  <select id="yearDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
  </select><br/>

  Country: <br/>
  <input type="text" name="country"/><br/>
</form>
<br/>
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

This is meant to output the values from the form to my VS the output window, but I get nothing. any ideas?

Comment: use jquery :   var queryString = $('#input').serialize();

Comment: Use this :  
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

Comment: `var formData = $('#input').serialize();`

Comment: Is ``document.getElementById(element).elements`` a thing? Are you sure shouldn't be using ``.childNodes``?

Comment: Are you sure that `console.log` should output the values to your VS output window?

Comment: @Rory I realized that later... I edited my comment

Comment: @Dekel Usually works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already using jQuery to attach your event handler, you may as well use it to select all the elements in the form using the `:input` selector. From there you can simply loop through them all using `each()` and output their values to the console, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('form :input').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="input">
    First Name: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>

    Last Name: <br/>
    <select id="lastName" style="text-align: center;">
    </select><br/>

    <p>Date of Birth:</p><br />

    Day: <br/>
    <select id="dayDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
    </select><br/>
    Month: <br/>
    <select id="monthDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
    </select><br/>
    Year: <br/>
    <select id="yearDropDown" style="text-align: center;">
    </select><br/>

    Country: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="country"/><br/>
</form>
<br/>
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Not sure about the downvoters, but I dont think this answers the original question. His code works (even though it's not a good javascript/jQuery code, and can be written much better with jQuery...)

Comment: Good approach, but I assume the OP also wants the values of the select fields too, if they would be filled. (+1 although)

Comment: @secelite this will get that. There are just no options in his current HTML to retrieve

Comment: Since he is already using jQuery, `.serializeArray` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin very possibly. However it would depend on what OPs intended use is. If he wants to work with the values directly in this loop then there's no point looping to create an array and looping again to process it. If he wants to store the array for use in multiple places the `serializeArray()` would be more appropriate

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for also expending my knowledge.

Comment: So I've implemented the code and it isn't working, I know it works when I press Run code snippet, but for some reason it's not working in my program.

Comment: I can't really help you without an error, or an example of the problem. As you can see it works in the snippet, so so long as you've included jQuery correctly and are running your code in document.ready (which you seem to be as there's no errors in the console) then I can't offer any more assistance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help anyway. I'll accept your answer as it may help people in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and get the data with one statement

```
var queryString = $('#input').serialize();
```

See this [live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8BcyShgvU2G1MPXG14rt?p=preview) for a demo.

Comment: `.serializeArray` would probably be closer to what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) will solve your problem.

This is your code as modificated:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var text = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                console.log(x[i].value);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Seems odd to use vanilla JS when JQuery's already being used, plus this won't work for the select elements.

Comment: this just for inputs. I you want to run it for selects too, you should add this `var y = document.getElementsByTagName("select")` then concat these arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Apply with same `Id` name with all input . your javascript was working ...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("input");
            var text = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                console.log(x.elements[i].value);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="input">

        First Name: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="input"/><br/>

        Last Name: <br/>
        <select id="lastName" style="text-align: center;" id="input">
        </select><br/>

        <p>Date of Birth:</p><br />

        Day: <br/>
        <select id="dayDropDown" style="text-align: center;" id="input">
        </select><br/>
        Month: <br/>
        <select id="monthDropDown" style="text-align: center;" id="input" >
       
  </select><br/>
        Year: <br/>
        <select id="yearDropDown" style="text-align: center;" id="input">
        </select><br/>

        Country: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="input"/><br/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you add the jquery-serialize-object  reference,so it may do the things become a bit easier:

```
 $('#input').submit(function(){
   var objForm = $(this).serializeObject();
    console.log(objForm);
 });
```

[Here you can find other examples and the jquery-serialize-object library for downloading](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $('form input, form select').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```